# Android - Keeping track of Threads

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity which, during its execution, kicks off a couple of `AsyncTask`s and a couple of `Thread`s.

If these continue when the activity is destroyed/recreated then all sorts of errors occur so my bright idea was to make each non UI thread register itself, adding itself to an `ArrayList<Thread>()` and `ArrayList<AsyncTask>()` meaning that I could, onDestroy(), iterate through these ArrayLists and destroy them like so:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    for(AsyncTask task : tasks)
        task.cancel(true);*

    for(Thread thread : threads)
        thread.interrupt();
}
```

Unfortunately this throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on the line marked with *. I tried wrapping each `for` loop in a `synchronize` block to make sure the `ArrayList`s aren't being modified by any other `Thread`s.

Do `AsyncTask`s destroy themselves on completion (and therefore throw the above error)?

Does anyone know of a better way of controlling Threads in an Android environment?

**EDIT**

Changing the code to use `for(int i =0 : i < array.size() ; i++)` seems to solve this problem but I would still like to know /why/ it happens:

```
    synchronized(tasks)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < tasks.size(); i++)
            tasks.get(i).cancel(true);
    }

    synchronized(threads)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < threads.size(); i++)
            threads.get(i).interrupt();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, AsyncTasks disappear, once they've run the onPostExecute and you've set the instance to null, or something similar. What are you doing in a Thread that you couldn't do in a Service or AsyncTask? Are you doing UI operations in your threads (like, runOnUIThread or something) that would cause these threads to error when the app isn't in foreground?

The nice thing about doing things in a Service, is you can broadcast that you're about to close the app, and stop any actions in the Service that you no longer need running, essentially hibernating the Service until you fire it up again when the app comes into foreground.

Comment: I'm running native methods which closely communicate with the java threads through semaphores and the like.

Comment: And, "disappear" as in they call a destroy() on themselves when no longer running?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old thread, but I will answer it anyways since this is a common problem people get into.

What is happening here is that the following code,

```
for(AsyncTask task : tasks)
    task.cancel(true);`
```

uses a for-each loop which needs `tasks` object to stay intact while it is iterating through it. My guess is that in the `onPostExecute()` of your task, you are removing it from this list, which modifies it and causes the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You don't prevent concurrent modifications unless **all** modifications in the app are surrounded by `synchronized`; just doing it here isn't enough.

Try using a synchronized collection:

```
// create the empty list
List tasks = Collections.synchronized(new ArrayList<AsyncTask>());
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned, I also synchronised the one other place in the code where the array is used (ie, is added to).

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask does indeed kill itself when doInBackground finishes.  For that matter, java threads do the same thing when run() finishes.  The call to cancel() will only return true or false depending on whether or not the asyncTask was able to be canceled.

ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when you try to modify something that's being used in a thread.  From what I understand, you're array list is being used in the UI thread to cancel the asynctasks and it's also being used in both asynctasks to register itself.  I'm guessing somewhere you don't have the array list collection synchronized.

Perhaps:

```
synchronized(tasks){
    for(int i=0; i < tasks.size(); i++){
       tasks.get(i).cancel(true);
    }
}
```

will fix it.  Make sure that tasks is also synchronized in all asyncTasks.  Or you can make it volatile.

But at any rate, by the time you're at onDestroy you're asyncTasks are probably be already done (or should be), so I don't see why you'd need to make sure they're canceled.  If you don't want them running when the user's left the app, then you should put it in onPause().

Comment: When the Activity is left - not the app.

As in my edit, that flavour of for loop is immune to this problem so I assume it is the methodology surrounding the other type of for loop (Likly using the `Iterator`).

Also, I think I may have confused you - when I say `destroy` i do not mean kill what I mean is mark itself for garbage collection. Threads do not do this upon finishing execution.